# ServiceStack + FluentValidation: Why do IReturnVoid DTOs get generic 400 response; but IReturn<T> get Validation Results?

Tags: servicestack

I have the following scenario:

- A DTO for handing a `POST` route
- An `AbstractValidator<DTO>` that gets fired when the service interface gets called

When I mark that DTO as `IReturnVoid` I get a standard `Exception` back in my client with an error: `"The remote server returned an error:  (400) Bad Request."`

If I change that DTO to `IReturn<SomeClass>` then I get a `WebServiceException` with the fluent validation results I'd expect.

This doesn't seem right. Is this by design? Is there a way I can fix this? Under normal circumstances, I don't need a return value from this route -- thus `IReturnVoid`.

Looking at the documentation, I cannot find any reason `IReturnVoid` should fail like this.

For now I am marking the DTO as `IReturn<bool>` and returning `true` but this feels like a hack.

Comment: re:This doesn't seem right. Would it feel right to return validation results for a DTO that should return Void/Nothing? I think by design IRetunVoid doesn't send data back in the Response so I'm not sure where the failed validation results would go for an IReturnVoid Request. IMO, if you're going to validate a Request you should have some type of Response for the failed rules (even if you just throw them away). If you don't want a Response (ie. IReturnVoid) an HTTP code (in this case 400) seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: `IReturnVoid` is just a helper for the strongly-typed controllers, though. I guess it also helps decorate the API self-generated documentation. And when something fails, SS already doesn't return your DTO type, but instead returns a different HTTP code with a different DTO. So why can't `void` work the same way? Under normal circumstances, it returns nothing back; but in the error case, you can expect to see *X*? I actually like your idea and will likely create a response DTO for void. But I'm just not seeing why there's a difference in the first place. Thank you for your comment!